# run asp.net core mvc Application in visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have already developed asp.net core MVC Application before in visual studio 2017
and I Decided to run and debug this app on visual studio code, What are the required changes for configuration in vs code and in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single change. VS code is an editor after all you go to your folder.
[image]

Not on the sln folder and run on the cmd

```
dotnet run
```

Answer (score 0):

So on VS Code which is a light version of Visual Studio Code.
Enter the command `dotnet build` and then `dotnet run`.
Click this link
 `Now listening on: http://localhost:5255`

It's the second line down and might be a little confusing as
it is not the last line of the output

[image: This is the output you should get]